# Import Warning: Not Importing Directory issues using wxPython, don't know how to fix

Tags: python, wxpython, warnings, python-import

I keep getting this warning every time I use wxPython:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 14581
    import locale
ImportWarning: Not importing directory '/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/locale': missing __init__.py
```

How do I fix this? I'm using wxPython on Mac.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, but not with wxPython, but with some Django project. Someone also named the directory for language files "locale". I'd like to run the application quietly with `-Wall`. In a perfect world there would be a possibility to add a `__noinit__.py`, which would tell the interpreter to never try to import this directory as a module ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just a warning; there is no need to fix anything here. You could suppress the warning, perhaps. But it is up to the `wxPython` project to properly silence that warning.

To suppress the warning, you can use the [`warnings` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='Not importing directory .*', module='wx.*')
```

Comment: The real problem is that wxPython shouldn't have a directory named `locale` at the same level as its subpackages, because that conflicts with the stdlib module of the same name. This may have been fixed, because in my 2.9.4.0 installation I don't have this problem. But it's possible that the problem is with the binary installer or something, not with the library itself, in which case my non-binary install wouldn't be evidence of anything.